# Server in Docker container connection refused, should I add time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond) to my tests?

Tags: docker, http, go

I am currently working on a server that is designed to be run in a Docker container.

Here is my setup method for my tests:

```
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    schedulerName := "scheduler1"
    IP, err := container.StartNewScheduler(schedulerName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Could not create container.")
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    serverIP = IP
    code := m.Run()
    cleanupContainer(schedulerName)
    os.Exit(code)
}
```

The line `container.StartNewScheduler(schedulername)` boots up a new docker container called "scheduler1" and tells it to run the server inside of it.

Next I run my tests with the container running in the background, right now I only have one test.

```
func TestNewScheduler(t *testing.T) {
    testCodeInput := "THIS IS A TEST"
    requestBody, err := json.Marshal(map[string]string{
        "Code": fmt.Sprintf("print(\"%s\")", testCodeInput),
    })

    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    url := fmt.Sprintf("http://%s:%d/execute/python", serverIP, 3000)
    contentType := "application/json"
    body := bytes.NewBuffer(requestBody)

    response := post(url, contentType, body, t)
    actual := parseOutput(response.Body, t)
    response.Body.Close()

    expected := fmt.Sprintf("{\"Stdout\":\"%s\\n\"}", testCodeInput)
    if actual != expected {
        t.Fatalf("Expected %s, but got %s", expected, actual)
    }
}
```

The problem that I am running into is sometimes I get a connection refused and sometimes I don't.

```
server_container_test.go:51: Post http://172.20.0.2:3000/execute/python: dial tcp 172.20.0.2:3000: connect: connection refused
```

I noticed that whenever I try and debug the issue everything seems to work fine. My running theory is because when I step through my code the container has more time to start up and get the server running inside it.

In order to test my Hypothesis I added a second post call in my post method with a timer set before I call it.

```
func post(url string, contentType string, body io.Reader, t *testing.T) *http.Response {
    t.Helper()
    response, err := http.Post(url, contentType, body)
    if err != nil {
        //There is an error where the container takes a second to boot up and so
        //the scheduler isn't running when the first request is sent, so we try
        //one more time here and  check again.
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond) <--- Right here
        response, err = http.Post(url, contentType, body)
        if err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
    return response
}
```

Does anyone else have any guesses as to what could be causing me this issue?

If my hypothesis is correct is this the best way to fix this? Is it a bad idea to add a time.Sleep to your tests?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after some more thought I changed up my source code, please let me know if you think this is a good solution to my problem. I am still learning Go and HTTP servers so any input is appreciated.

Here is my fix/idea:

Previously once the container was created I just returned it's IP address and forgot about it.

Now I create a go routine that repeatedly tries to send a POST request to the server. If it doesn't fail then I send true through a channel and close the function.

```
    IP := info.NetworkSettings.Networks[networkName].IPAddress
    works := make(chan bool)
    ctx, canelRoutine := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer canelRoutine()

    go func(ctx context.Context) {
        requestBody, _ := json.Marshal(map[string]string{
            "Code": "print()",
        })
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        default:
            for {
                _, err := http.Post(
                    fmt.Sprintf("http://%s:%d/execute/python", IP, 3000),
                    "application/json",
                    bytes.NewBuffer(requestBody),
                )
                if err == nil {
                    works <- true
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }(ctx)
```

After sending the goroutine off I create a timer and and wait for either the timer to return or the goroutine.

```
    timer := time.After(500 * time.Millisecond)
    select {
    case <-works:
        return IP, nil
    case <-timer:
        return IP, &UnreachableContainerError{name: schedulerName}
    }
```

The upside to this solution is I have now introduced an UnreachableContainerError which allows me to be more specific about my error messages and it can be checked on the receiving side. I also send the IP address back either way just in case the client needs it for some other reason.

Here is the full StartNewScheduler method in case you wanted to see it.

```
//StartNewScheduler starts a new scheduler with the given options.
//returns the IP address for the given scheduler.
func StartNewScheduler(schedulerName string) (string, error) {
    ///Defaults
    dockerfile := "Dockerfile_standard"
    networkName := "scheduler-cluster"
    imageID := "lkelly93/scheduler_image:latest"

    cli, err := client.NewEnvClient()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    err = createDefaultImageIfNeeded(
        cli,
        imageID,
        dockerfile)

    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    err = createSchedulerClusterNetworkIfNeeded(cli, networkName)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    ctx := context.Background()
    resp, err := cli.ContainerCreate(
        ctx,
        &container.Config{Image: imageID},
        &container.HostConfig{
            NetworkMode: container.NetworkMode(networkName),
            Privileged:  true,
        },
        nil,
        schedulerName,
    )

    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    err = cli.ContainerStart(ctx, resp.ID, types.ContainerStartOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    //Get container IP
    info, err := cli.ContainerInspect(ctx, resp.ID)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    IP := info.NetworkSettings.Networks[networkName].IPAddress
    works := make(chan bool)
    ctx, canelRoutine := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer canelRoutine()

    go func(ctx context.Context) {
        requestBody, _ := json.Marshal(map[string]string{
            "Code": "print()",
        })
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        default:
            for {
                _, err := http.Post(
                    fmt.Sprintf("http://%s:%d/execute/python", IP, 3000),
                    "application/json",
                    bytes.NewBuffer(requestBody),
                )
                if err == nil {
                    works <- true
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }(ctx)

    timer := time.After(500 * time.Millisecond)
    select {
    case <-works:
        return IP, nil
    case <-timer:
        return IP, &UnreachableContainerError{name: schedulerName}
    }
}
```

Comment: For all that this seems like a lot of code, it's a good approach: the container is actually running when it answers HTTP requests, and not before.  You might put a delay in the `for` loop that tries to call the container, and you probably should put the `select` statement inside the `for` loop (so you stop pinging the container when the context is cancelled).

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the response. I already have the select statement outside the for loop should I just remove that one and put one inside the for loop or should I do both?

Answer (score -3):

You could run the test code inside of a container, started via docker compose with the option [depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on).

Comment: The point of these tests is to make sure the server is working inside of the docker container. I already have other tests to test the server outside of the container, so I don't think this will work.

Comment: `depends_on:` does not solve this problem.  (It ensures the target container exists, and DNS resolution will succeed, but it does not ensure the process in the target container is running.)